# How to make offset for ScrollintoView function

Tags: javascript, html, function, js-scrollintoview

So I have a few buttons that scroll to different places of my website and highlight it yellow for a second. They work well, but the only problem is, since my top nav is `40px` tall, some of the element that it scrolls to is covered. Is there any way to offset the `scrollintoview` property by 45px (extra 5 for border & reasonable margin) so it doesn't get covered? thank you! This is the code for one of the buttons:

```
function Go_to_Q_and_A() {
    var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName('QA')[0];
    divElement.scrollIntoView();
    divElement.classList.add('highlighted');

    setTimeout(function() {
        divElement.classList.remove('highlighted');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple CSS only solution, add the following property: `.QA { scroll-margin-top: 45px; }`
It will do as it says - add a top margin to the page scroll so that the fixed navbar is taken into account.

```js
function Go_to_Q_and_A() {
    var divElement = document.getElementsByClassName('QA')[0];
    divElement.scrollIntoView();
    divElement.classList.add('highlighted');

    setTimeout(function() {
        divElement.classList.remove('highlighted');
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.QA { scroll-margin-top: 45px; }
.highlighted { background-color: yellow; }
.tall { height: 1000px }
```

```html
<button onclick="Go_to_Q_and_A()">QA</button>
<div class="tall">Lorem</div>
<div class="QA">QA</div>
<div class="tall">Lorem</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to set it to `scroll-margin-top:90px;` for it to work though